# Load JavaScript depending on previously asynchronously loaded JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
<script src="script1.js" async></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

`script2.js` is depending on `script1.js`. Since `script1.js` isn't loaded completely when `script2.js` is executed, it doesn't work. How to fix this?

Edit: I cannot remove the `async` attribute and I can only modify the content of `script2.js`.

Comment: do you need the `async`?

Comment: I cannot remove the `async`.

Comment: why can't you?? Async should only be used for scripts that have no dependants. You have a dependant so you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Because it comes from elsewhere. Besides, it speeds up the site.

Comment: Can you modify the content of either script?

Comment: I can modify only the content of `script2.js`.

Comment: What's the use of "speeding up your site" if it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, as already mentioned, I cannot remove the `async`.

Comment: In the second script, you could try fetching the first script element, and giving it an `onload` handler, which would run the code within the second script. Some old versions of IE don't support `onload` on scripts and you'd need to make sure the first script hasn't already loaded and if it has, you'd need to manually invoke the `onload` function.

Comment: ...by the way, it's helpful to put the constraints you've describe here directly in the question. Any answer is going to depend on these details.

Comment: You're right. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first script must be async, better also put the second as async.

A naive solution is to regularly look for a global variable that the first script may be exporting.

Let's say script1 attaches `script1export` to window, you can do something like:

```
// Regularly check test, and once it is true, call callback.
function waitFor(test, callback, checksPerSec){
   if(test()){
     callback();
   } else {
     checksPerSec = checksPerSec || 10;
     setTimeout(function(){
       waitFor(test, callback, checksPerSec);
     }, 1000 / checksPerSec);
   }
}

waitFor(function(){
  return "script1export" in window;
}, function(){
   // script 2 content
});
```

It is not ideal, but it will work.

Answer (score -1):

```
// script 1
if (!window.myObj1){
    window.myObj1 = script1Obj1;
}

// script 2
if (!window.myObj2){
    window.myObj2 = script2Obj2;
}


// script 1 & script 2

if (window.myObj1 && window.myObj2){
    // run...   
}
```